There are some videos that don't work with the normal VideoPlayerController package
We Use Packages:
~ video_player: ^2.8.6
~ chewie: ^1.8.1

Example Code:
class Display extends StatefulWidget {


  Display({super.key});

  @override
  State<Display> createState() => _DisplayState();
}

class _DisplayState extends State<Display> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  VideoPlayerController? controllerVideoWorkout;
  ChewieController? chewieController;

  @override
  void initState(){
    controllerVideoWorkout = VideoPlayerController.file(
      "pathVideo",
      videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(mixWithOthers: true)
    )..initialize().then((value){
      controllerVideoWorkout!.setVolume(0.0);
        setState(() {});
      });

      chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: controllerVideoWorkout!,
        looping: true
      );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      child: Center(
        child: Chewie(
          controller: chewieController!
        )
      )
    )
  }
}


Example Video:

I experienced something strange, some videos used this code smoothly and had no problems, but I found some videos didn't run normally, such as Example Video.
I want to ask if there is a solution to solve this problem?, without using the chewie package I experienced the same thing, I suspect there is something in the video_player package, please help everyone,
The oddity that I experienced was, the example video has a duration of 11 seconds but can only move at second 4, at seconds 1-3 the video doesn't move
Which I expected to run the video smoothly, starting from the first second
